# Optimize staff scheduling by minimizing the sum of a particular variable

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

So, this might be a bit of a long shot because it is quite a complex problem or at least it is to me.

My general problem is optimizing a staff schedule. I have inputs such as project info and employee info. Each employee is a part of one of four teams and has a particular skill set and a particular amount of available hours per week. Projects have a required team, skill set, start and end date, estimated hours to complete, and a priority associated with them.

I have developed a heuristic model that takes these features into consideration with constraints such as: employees can't work over their available hours per week, projects must be completed by employees within the specified team, projects must be completed in the start - end date time frame. The model I developed is certainly not optimal by any means and just divides the estimated hours by the amount of staff working on it and then divides that number by the amount of weeks it will take to complete to get the hours per week per staff.

I am now trying to figure out how to optimize it. I'll give an example to explain how I am thinking of doing it. My objective function is to minimize the sum of time over-allocation per employee.

Let's say I have 3 projects to schedule, and I have 5 possible staff that satisfy the project skill set and team requirements:

[image]

How can I reduce the number of over-allocations assuming I have a counter to measure that? I know that PuLP is probably the best package for this but I need some guidance on how to get started.

TLDR; I have a functioning heuristic that takes constraints into consideration and I want to optimize it by minimizing an objective function. Any linear programming or general advice is much appreciated.

Important Note: The amount of projects being scheduled varies so I cannot make x for loops if I have x projects to be scheduled.

Comment: The best advice I can give is to first write down a mathematical model of the problem before starting to code.

Comment: Just to add to Erwin's comment, I'd recommend googling 'MILP shceduling problems'. There will be a large number of examples to get ideas/inspiration from. Good luck!